# CASE statement returns NULLS for rows in the other columns

Tags: sql, database, vertica

CASE statement is returning null for the empty rows of the other column.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    CASE WHEN Category = 'Ethnic_Group' THEN EMPLOYEE_ETHNICITY
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'ethnicity',
    CASE WHEN Category = 'RACE' THEN EMPLOYEE_RACE
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'race'
FROM EMPLMOYEE_TABLE
```

| employee_id | ethnicity | race |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | African-American | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | OTHERS |
| 1 | NULL | BLACK |

I would like something similar to this:

| employee_id | ethnicity | race |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | African-American | BLACK |
| 1 | African-American | OTHERS |

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is what it should be doing. Is there something you were not expecting? What were you hoping to see? Please edit your post with your desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes to the post

Comment: OK, I see what you're expecting. But have to ask why you want that? I assume mike is employee ID 1 and john is 2. If that's the case, why do you want mike info with data on the john row?

Comment: So... isntead of null you want to fill with "m"? Then change `ELSE NULL` with `ELSE 'm'`.

Comment: I made changes to the table, please see the new edit

Comment: Just saw that my query makes no sense. Can you just show a cut-out of `employee_table` with `employee_id,category,ethnicityrace` and the values 'African-American' for `ethnicity` and 'BLACK' and 'OTHERS' for `race`? I think the query can be made more elegant ....

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind sharing what *is* happening along with what you want to have happen? I see there are NULL fields in the ethnicity column. If you can walk the ethnicity column from the race column (and there aren't nulls here as well) I'd do:

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN EMPLOYEE_RACE = 'BLACK' 
            THEN COALESCE(EMPLOYEE_ETHNICITY, 'African-American')
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'ethnicity',
    CASE 
        WHEN EMPLOYEE_ETHNICITY = 'African-American' 
            THEN COALESCE(EMPLOYEE_RACE, 'BLACK')
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'race'
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE_TABLE
```

Comment: Note I just did this for BLACK / African-American. You'd need to add a new WHEN statement for what ever other combos you see in your data.

Comment: no it is not going to work, because I have more options then this

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your dataset currently looks like, so we can understand what the current state is and how you're trying to reformat it?

You said the case statement is returning null for the empty rows of the 'other' column -- what would you like returned instead? where would that data come from?

Answer (score 0):

It's about filling NULL holes with the data from previous rows.

I'm taking advantage that the sort I use, by `ethnicity` follows the NULLS LAST rule.

```
WITH
-- your input, don't use in final query ...
employee_table(employee_id,ethnicity,race) AS (
          SELECT 1,'African-American',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,  NULL            ,'OTHERS'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,  NULL            ,'BLACK'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
holes_filled AS (
  SELECT
    employee_id
  , LAST_VALUE(ethnicity IGNORE NULLS) OVER w
  , race
  FROM employee_table
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY ethnicity)
)
SELECT 
  * 
FROM holes_filled
WHERE race IS NOT NULL;
-- out  employee_id |    LAST_VALUE    |  race  
-- out -------------+------------------+--------
-- out            1 | African-American | OTHERS
-- out            1 | African-American | BLACK
```